# Material UI react missing action table header

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I'm currently using material UI and I want to add an action button in my material table but when I tried to add a table it's not showing the action header.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you would have to add another `TableCell` to your `TableRow` inside `TableHead` since the body is not linked to your header row.

I would recommend naming the header of this column something like "Actions" in case you add more "actions".

```js
<TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            ...
            <TableCell> Actions </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          ...
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
</TableContainer>
```

If you want to add a Tooltip, you can try wrapping it inside a `Tooltip` component ([Material-Ui Tooltip](https://material-ui.com/components/tooltips/))

```js
<TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            ...
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          ...
          <Tooltip title="Save User">
             <Button/>
          </Tooltip>
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
</TableContainer>
```